# Magento grid _addButton that filters collection from the controller. How?

Tags: grid, controllers, admin-controller

we have a grid where we add a button. It triggers the shownewonlyAction in the controlller. But I have no idea how to set a filter (or even reset all filters) in the controller shownewonlyAction ().

**question**: How do I set a filter in the controller action? (something like `state=processing`) or `preorder_status IS NULL`

thx

```
    $this->_addButton('shownewonly', array(
        'label'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Show new only'),
        'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/shownewonly')}')",
        'class'   => 'index'
    ));
```

this is what I have tried

```
    public function shownewonlyAction()
{;
    //$this->setDefaultFilter(array('preorder_status' => null));
    //$data = $this->prepareFilterString('pp.preorder_status IS NULL');
    //$this->_setFilterValues($data);
    //$filter = base64_encode('preorder_status=');
    //Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->setParam('filter', $filter);
    $this->indexAction();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to store the filter in the registry or session in the controller file and get it again in the grid.

Something like this in the controller file

`Mage::getSingleton("admin/session")->setFilter($filter);`

and access this value in the function `_prepareCollection()` in the grid file

```
$filter = Mage::getSingleton("admin/session")->getFilter();
        if (!empty($filter)) { 
            foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
                $collection->addFieldToFilter($key,$value);
            }
        }
```

I don't think there is another way